# Building Cocoa touch framework with c++11 code

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, c++11, frameworks

I am trying to make an iOS framework. My code includes c++11 features.
When I build the framework target I get errors such as:

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/ctime:56:9: No member named 'clock_t' in the global namespace`

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/ctime:58:9: No member named 'time_t' in the global namespace; did you mean 'size_t'?`

How can I resolve this? Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

Here is my Apple LLVM 6.0 - Language-c++ settings:
[image]

Regular iOS project with that c++11 code compiles without errors.

Answer (score 1):

you need to explicitly add libc++ as a linked library under general tab.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how far it will work fine in your scenario. I got similar kind of error when I tried to compile and build so. I will share what I did :

1.Goto your project Build Settings.

2.Click Build Settings.

3.Search for **Apple LLVM 6.0 - Language-c++** .

4.set **c++ standard library** as **libstdc++** .

Then try compile the project.

This might not the exact solution.

I just shared what worked for me when I am facing the similar kind of errors as yours.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the C++ Language Dialect to `C++11`? It's in the same place as the C++ standard library setting:

1. Go to Build Settings
2. Select your Target, and click Build Settings.
3. Search for **Apple LLVM 6.0 - Language-C++**
4. Set **C++ Language Dialect** to `C++11`.

You might also have to set the **C++ Standard Library** to `libc++`.

Comment: I have updated post with compiler settings information

Answer (score 0):

Xcode adds all headers to the "Headers" build phase by default. So, I solved my issue by removing all unnecessary C++ headers from the build phase.